# JTable runtime calculation?

Tags: java, swing, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

This is my group project part. When I enter the customer id and press OK, the customer details appear in tabular format. The table contains columns like: Sunday, rate, Saturday, 
rate, other, rate like.

My problem is I want to enter the integer number, calculate it and then store it in a database.  Means run time in table I want to enter the number, calculate and need to be stored in database. What to do? Thanks in advance.

```
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import java.awt.EventQueue;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.sql.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
 import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
 import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
 public class TestTable 
 {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    TestTable testTable = new TestTable();
}
public TestTable() 
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            try
            {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(new TestTable.Bill());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}    
public class Bill extends JPanel implements ActionListener ,CellEditorListener  
{
    JTextField textFieldId;
    JLabel l1;
    JLabel l2;
    JButton b1,b2,b3;
    JTextField sun,sunr,sat,satr,oth,othr;
    float sum1,totall;
    ResultSet rs1 = null;
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();       
    private int rows;
    Double value;
    public Bill() 
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());            
        JPanel fields = new JPanel();
        textFieldId = new JTextField(10);
        l1 = new JLabel("New Customer Entry :-");
        l2 = new JLabel("Customer Id");
        b1 = new JButton("OK");
        b2 = new JButton("Calculate");
        b3 = new JButton("Print");
        fields.add(l2);
        fields.add(textFieldId);
        fields.add(b1);
        fields.add(b2);
        fields.add(b3);
        add(fields, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        b3.addActionListener(this);
        // Don't forget to add a table.
        add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(model)));
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        System.out.println("You clicked the button");
        Connection con;
        if (e.getSource() == b1) 
        {
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            try 
            {

                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:devendra");
                ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT  * FROM Customer where Customer_Id = ?");
                // You must bind the parameter with a value...
                ps.setString(1, textFieldId.getText());
                rs1 = ps.executeQuery();
                model.addColumn("Customer_Id");
                model.addColumn("Customer_Name");
                model.addColumn("Contact");
                model.addColumn("Paper_Name");
                model.addColumn("Sunday");
                model.addColumn("Rate");
                model.addColumn("Satarday");
                model.addColumn("Rate");
                model.addColumn("Other Day");
                model.addColumn("Rate");
                model.addColumn("Price");
                model.setRowCount(0);
                while (rs1.next()) 
                {                           
                        model.addRow(new Object[]{rs1.getString(1),rs1.getString(2),rs1.getString(3),rs1.getString(4),rs1.getString(5),
                            rs1.getString(6),rs1.getString(7),rs1.getString(8),rs1.getString(9),rs1.getString(10)});
                }
             //   Vector data = model.getDataVector();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You successfully Enter the Entry");
            } 
            catch (SQLException s) 
            {
                System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter the Detail Correctly");
            } catch (Exception exp) 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Failed to perform query: " + exp.getMessage());
            } finally 
            {
                try {
                    ps.close();
                } 
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }                
        } 
        if (e.getSource() == b2)     
        {
             int rowCount = model.getRowCount();


             for(int i =1; i<rowCount;i++)
             {
                 Double valuea = (Double) model.getValueAt(i, 5 );
                 Double valueb = (Double) model.getValueAt(i, 6 );
                 Double valuec = (Double) model.getValueAt(i, 7 );
                 Double valued = (Double) model.getValueAt(i, 8 );
                 Double valuee = (Double) model.getValueAt(i, 9 );
                 Double valuef = (Double) model.getValueAt(i, 10 ); 
                  double value; 
                  value = Double.parseDouble( String.valueOf( valuea ) ) * Double.parseDouble( String.valueOf( valueb ) ); 
                  model.setValueAt( value, i, 10 ); 
             }

    }
```

}

```
    @Override
    public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void editingCanceled(ChangeEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }



}
```

}

Comment: _I want to enter the number, calculate [and] store in database._ What's stopping you? Where is your `UPDATE` statement? You're asking someone to debug/revise lengthy code run against an implied schema on an inaccessible database using a poorly supported driver. L&F should be irrelevant, and only one database attribute is required. Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem.

Comment: i just edited the code.when i run these code it get successfully execution but i not give me proper output as i want it. now what to do please tell me???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how your `INSERT` can succeed: the parentheses don't balance, and `setValueAt()`—were its text actually invoked—returns `void`; check the log. You appear to be inserting a single attribute, while the `Customer` relation has 11. If you mean to `UPDATE` the `Total` attribute, note that your schema violates [*normal form*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), in that `Total` depends on a subset of other attributes. Consult with your group about correcting the schema. Re-factor your formula for `sum1` into a method that can be reused whenever `Total` should be displayed.

Comment: please debug these code in your system.when table appear i enter manually entry in front of column where column start from Sunday and ends on rate and that whole calculation shown in total column..
and my team get feasted how to do these code..@trashgod
if u can then help me out from these problem
:) please run in your system..

Comment: Also consider one of the `model.addRow()` methods, rather than `model.getDataVector()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your code is correct. How it is adding row or column. I think there is need to provide `table model` when you done adding all things to table model, also make a new `function` that will calculate sum. Also add columns in constructor i.e. only once. Consult with your group.

Comment: do u have any suggestion for these problem.
actually we all do not know any further than these if we got any idea or solution then we edit our code.
but u too help me out from these situation problem.Thanks for the  help...

Comment: A `DefaultTableModel` is a `TableModel`.

Comment: can u give me tutorial link from that link i can learn more...?

Comment: hmm.. here is a lengthy code no one will compile this on his pc, edit it to the point. I think you are displaying the data in the table. But not calculating right. What you want to calculate and on which criteria and from which fields? You are getting 6 values from table but multiplying only 2. Also you did not catch the exception see [link:](http://www.coderanch.com/t/553738/java/java/double-parseDouble-Exception) may be this is problem. Or debug your code on your pc line by line

Comment: is this solved the problem. I judged that you are from india? am I right?